# Serial Moniror, '\r' and Realterm

Tags: serial, print

I'm wanting the results from each of the 6 ultrasound modules to print on their respected line after new results have been generated instead of spitting out a continuous flow (see attached image). I've downloaded Realterm and got the results to show on there as I've read that the serial monitor can't do that but I don't know where to put the '\r' syntax within my script as I have multiple serial.prints to display the data I need.

Here is a section for 1 of the ultrasound modules, they are just repeated for the differing modules.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: serial monitor]

````
  //Object Ahead Distance.
  long duration1, distance1;
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, LOW);
  duration1 = pulseIn(echoPin1, HIGH);
  distance1 = (duration1/2) / 29.1;

   delay(500);
   if (distance1 >= 40){
    Serial.print("Nothing Ahead, Okay");
    Serial.print(distance1);
    Serial.println("cm");}
   else if (distance1 <= 39 || distance1 >= 29){
    Serial.print("Vehicle Ahead, Slow ");
    Serial.print(distance1);
    Serial.println("cm");}```
````

Answer (score 1):

`\r` returns the cursor to the start of the current line. You can't use it to go back up to previous lines.

Instead you need to learn ANSI escape sequences to move the cursor around.

For example `Serial.print("\e[2J");` will clear the entire screen. `Serial.print("\e[1;1H");` will move the cursor to the top left corner of the screen (the coordinates are `\e[{Y};{X}H` by the way).

You can also add colour and all sorts of other nice things, none of which the Arduino IDE's "Serial Monitor" can do.

You can find a good reference of ANSI escape codes [here](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797).

Comment: Thank you, Serial.print("\e[1;1H"); worked a treat